# XML sort by element

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

i want to sort all posts elements by the "Title" element through an xsl, but I am stuck.

```
<data>
    <post>
        <Title>AMNOG</Title>
        <Content>text</Content>
    </post>
    <post>
        <Title>Supply</Title>
        <Content>text</Content>
    </post>
    <post>
        <Title>Byw</Title>
        <Content>text</Content>
    </post>
</data>
```

This is my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/post">
      <xsl:sort select="Title"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

isn't working, any suggestions?

thx Marco

Comment: *"isn't working"* is not a good description of a problem. Always show both the expected and the actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying) (to copy all nodes as-is) and then use the xsl:sort in the apply-templates of a template matching `data` (which overrides the identity transform)...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="Title"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDg

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your sorting. The reason why your attempt "isn't working" is that you are not writing anything to the output.

You did not post the expected result, so I am just guessing you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="post">
            <xsl:sort select="Title"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```